# Is there a way to have multidimensional config arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, config

I want to create my own custom config data in the application section of Codeigniter, but was wondering if we can build two dimensional config arrays.

Example of `application/config/myconfig.php`:

```
$myconfigarray = array('row1'=> array( 'col1'=>'col1val',
                                       'col2'=>'col2val',
                                       'col3'=>'col3val' ),
                       'row2'=> array( 'col1'=>'col1val',
                                       'col2'=>'col2val',
                                       'col3'=>'col3val' ));
```

Currently by default at least, Codeigniter only seems to support one dimensional config arrays. How can I use multidimensional arrays?

Comment: You should elaborate more. Explain what you want to happen, what you tried to make it work, and what actually happened. Right now the question doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: ok np.  so for example the data in the application/config/config.php file, has only one dimensional array, called config, can we make that config array into 2 dimensional and does codeigniter provide methods/functions to work with the 2d arrays?

Comment: Post the config array you want to use and explain what's not working. Just click [edit] to add more information to your post.

Comment: k i posted an example config array, this is generally how i want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have configuration arrays in any size shape or form. Getting them to work entirely depends on what you want to do with them, how you're loading them, and how you're reading them.

I think your problem is that you need to rename `$myconfigarray` to `$config`:

> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html
>
> **Note**: If you do create your own config files use the same format as
>   the primary one, storing your items in an array called `$config`

So for your example, let's say the file is called `myconfig.php`:

```
$this->load->config('myconfig');
foreach (config_item('row1') as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k.' = '.$v;
}
```

This would print:

```
col1 = col1val
col2 = col2val
col3 = col3val
```

If you need to access a certain index, you'd have to do something like this:

```
$item = config_item('row1');
echo $item['col1']; // col1val
```

If you happen to be running PHP 5.4 you can access it like so:

```
echo config_item('row1')['col1'];
```

Comment: Yes of course, why *wouldn't* it work? How are you loading and reading the config file?

Comment: ok using codeigniters functions how can i access a 2d config array?

Comment: ok examplee, codeigntiers function to access the config array items is this:  $lang = $this->config->item('itemname');  but what if the array was 2d, does codeigniter have a function to access a 2d config array?

Comment: Yeah, don't let the fact that you're using a framework make you forget PHP ;) After all, that's what it's built with - it's not magic.